# Ubuntu 22.04 flannel cni0 degraded carrier

Tags: networking, kubernetes

I'm working with kubernetes on Ubuntu 22.04. We can see networking issues showing up in the syslog with flannel. In the logs you can see various networking links going up and down after 2s. The cni0 is in status degraded carrier.   Can anyone help ?  Should it be in a better state ?

Calling systemctl status systemd-networkd.service return the text below.

```
rgadmin@ubuntu:/var/log$ networkctl
IDX LINK         TYPE     OPERATIONAL      SETUP     
  1 lo           loopback carrier          unmanaged
  2 eth0         ether    routable         configured
  3 enP43331s1   ether    enslaved         unmanaged
  4 kube-ipvs0   ether    off              unmanaged
  5 flannel.1    vxlan    routable         unmanaged
  6 cni0         bridge   degraded-carrier unmanaged
```